# How to bring in user sign in for a hyperledger fabric web app?

Tags: authentication, hyperledger-fabric, x509certificate

I am trying out a sample hyperledger fabric app. I am thinking to develop a web app that can communicate with fabric chaincode and execute chaincode functions. But inorder to uniquely identify a user, the certificate is required. How can I achieve a user login mechanism in my web app (for example with username, password) such that it will identify the user who logged in and is calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Mohamed Noushad

It is very simple

As we know once we register a user and enroll we will get a private key and a certificate to us. It will be difficult to manage the keys by the users

So, traditional users are more comfortable with usernames and passwords rather thank keys. So, Create a database on top of user keys. `username, user`

user is for fabric and username is for your database. Or you can use the username for both

You handle the keys and the user needs to authenticate to prove that the set of keys belongs to him. Once the user authenticates with creds in the database using a normal username and password then you allow him to interact with fabric with the key enabled by you on behalf of the user.

Certificates can be stored in three different ways

- local kvs (file system)
- couch dB kvs
- Hardware wallets (HSM)

This is just one suggestion. We can do (n) No of ways. just think!!

Comment: So, say if I say that I use an username password logic for traditional users to sign in, shere will i be saving the certificate and keys. What I understand is it must be in a middleware right. If it's in a middleware where our database logic to access the path is written, isnt it the wrong practise to store all certificate and keys which is a honey pot for hackers ?

Comment: You can use kvs store as three types I will update the answer